# There is a way to make articles have an ownership feature

Tags: profile, knowledge, ownership

I'm dealing with salesforce knowledge, and i'm searching a way to make Users with Manage Articles enabled, to work only on the articles assigned to them and not to be able to work (modify, publish etc) with all articles.

I would find something similar to the hierarchy and ownership present for the other objects. Anyone know any approach?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way to achieve this through a validation rule on Knowledge Type, which works fine at my org.

```
NOT(ISNEW()) 
&& ($User.Id !=  AssignedToId) 
&& NOT(ISNULL(AssignedById)) 
&& NOT(ISNULL( CreatedById))
```

*You may change the rule based on your need.*